# How can I turn a mongoid document into JSON stripping out embedded document ids, but keeping the main document id?

Tags: ruby, json, mongoid

I have a document that has some embedded documents (and some of those have further embedded documents).

I want to return the document content as JSON but without all the IDs for the embedded documents.

I can do this:  mydoc.to_json(:except => :_id)
but that strips all BSON IDs, including the one for mydoc.

Is there some other way to *only* strip the embedded document IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `to_json` is actually two steps here:

1. Call `as_json` to get a Hash.
2. Convert that Hash to a string of JSON.

So you could use `as_json` instead of `to_json` to build a Hash without any `_id`s, then put the `_id` you care about back in, and finally convert to JSON:

```
mydoc.as_json(:except => :_id).merge('_id' => mydoc.id).to_json
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up coming up with myself. I thought there'd maybe be a fancier option but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for some sort of explicit "create collection" but it seems that Mongoid and Moped want to create collections as side effects of the initial insert or creating indexes.

Comment: One interesting change I made... I start with the small hash so as to have the ID first:  {"_id" => mydoc.id).merge(mydoc.as_json(except: "_id").to_json     This puts the ID field right at the front of the hash (which doesn't really matter but looks better when viewing the data)

Comment: That will be closer to what a plain `to_json` would give you and might be more readable.